# AngularJS 1.5.5 submitting not working when aliasing the controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, submit

I got the code below

```
<form ng-submit="addCust.submit()" ng-controller="AddCustomerCtrl as addCust"> 
    <div> <input type="text" ng-model="addCust.cName" required/> </div> 
    <div> <input type="text" ng-model="addCust.cCity" required/> </div>
    <div> <button id="f1" type="submit" >Add Customer</button> </div>
</form>
```

The controller.js is contains the below code

```
helloWorldControllers.controller('AddCustomerCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function AddCustomerCtrl($scope, $location) {
        $scope.submit = function(){ console.log('AddCustomerCtrl.submit !');
        $location.path('/addedCustomer/' + $scope.cName + "/" + $scope.cCity); }; 
    }
]);
```

Every thing is ok if I avoid to alias the control in HTML

```
("AddCustomerCtrl as addCust")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `$scope` when using the **Controller as** syntax. Your controller should be:

```
helloWorldControllers.controller('AddCustomerCtrl', ['$location',
    function AddCustomerCtrl($location) {
        this.submit = function(){ 
            console.log('AddCustomerCtrl.submit !');
            $location.path('/addedCustomer/' + this.cName + "/" + this.cCity); 
        }; 
    }
]);
```

Note that if you need to access `this` when a promise resolves you'll need to create a separate local variable because `this` will no longer be in context when the promise resolves.

Comment: I don't believe this code will work as this will reference the submit function, not the controller when its code is executing.

Comment: @MikeFeltman It will work fine, as evidenced by [this simple JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/js5y0dxm/).

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't really show that, but I added a bit to it and it does work. It's still not recommended to use this in that fashion.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Sigh...[updated the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/js5y0dxm/1/) to show that it really does work. This is basic stuff and I did point out in my original answer that if the OP needs to access `this` when a promise resolves that there is an additional step. What you are describing as an issue with `this` does not occur when calling a simple function on the controller.

Comment: Yeah, we're posting at the same time. It's still not the best practice though.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below controller code :

```
helloWorldControllers.controller('AddCustomerCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
     function ($scope, $location) {
        var addCust = this;
        addCust.submit = function(){
            console.log('AddCustomerCtrl.submit !');
            $location.path('/addedCustomer/' + $scope.cName + "/" + $scope.cCity);
        }; 
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use controllerAs the properties are referenced with the alias everywhere. So you should have addCust.cName and addCust.cCity in your code. I'd recommend not injecting $scope into your controller at all and removing all references to it from the code. If you're not familiar with it, the generally accepted best practices for this are well documented here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md.

```
helloWorldControllers.controller('AddCustomerCtrl', ['$scope', 
     function ($location) {
        var ctrl= this;
        ctrl.submit = function(){
            console.log('AddCustomerCtrl.submit !');
            $location.path('/addedCustomer/' + $ctrl.cName + "/" + ctrl.cCity);
        }; 
    }
]);
```

Comment: This will throw an error on `$location.path` because of the injection mismatch.

Comment: Yeah, I edited that out just before you posted your comment.